# Posted html markup is being clipped in ASP.NET MVC3 controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, concatenation

I am posting some markup from an admin's html editor to a server controller like this:

```
        var dataString = 'id=' + id +
                         '&name=' + name +
                         '&nameEngl=' + nameEngl +
                         '&description=' + description +
                         '&descriptionEngl=' + descriptionEngl +
                         '&imageName=' + imageName +
                         '&previewImageName=' + previewImageName +
                         '&types=' + types +
                         '&bottomAreaHtml=' + bottomAreaHtml +
                         '&bottomAreaHtmlEngl=' + bottomAreaHtmlEngl +
                         '&slug=' + slug +
                         '&__RequestVerificationToken=' + encodeURIComponent($("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#EditProjectActionUrl").val(),
            data: dataString,
            success: function (result) {
                RefreshProjectsList();
                form.find("#divStatus-p").hide();
                form.closest('.modal-popup').dialog('close');
            }
        });
```

As you can see `dataString` is a large string with markup, but nevertheless, I see via browser requests telemetry that is is being posted correctly to the server.

On the server I am recieving the posted data via controller's action:

```
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)] 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProject(string id, string name, string nameEngl, string description, string descriptionEngl, string customCSS, string imageName, string previewImageName, string types, string bottomAreaHtml, string bottomAreaHtmlEngl, string slug)
    {
```

At the point of method invokation, the default binder populates all the params. The problem that `bottomAreaHtml` parameter contains a clipped (not full) markup string. What's the problem here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a concatenated markup string. Concatenation is the process of joining two strings into one. Do you mean truncated (broken off before the end)?

Comment: Sorry, I misused the term. What I meant to say was a "clipped" string. I've updated the question and I have already came up with the solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach here. Instead of having so many arguments to your `EditProject` action, create an object which has properties which match those arguments. Example:

```
public class ProjectSettings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string nameEngl{ get; set; } 
    public string description{ get; set; } 
    public string descriptionEngl{ get; set; } 
    public string customCSS{ get; set; } 
    public string imageName{ get; set; } 
    public string previewImageName{ get; set; } 
    public string types{ get; set; } 
    public string bottomAreaHtml{ get; set; } 
    public string bottomAreaHtmlEngl{ get; set; } 
    public string slug{ get; set; } 
}
```

Then, you can just pass the object itself to the action, and the model binder will do the heavy lifting for you.

```
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)] 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProject(ProjectSettings projectSettings)
{
    //...
}
```

And your JavaScript can use objects too!

```
    var settings = {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'nameEngl': nameEngl,
        'description': description,
        'descriptionEngl': descriptionEngl,
        'imageName': imageName,
        'previewImageName': previewImageName,
        'types': types,
        'bottomAreaHtml': bottomAreaHtml,
        'bottomAreaHtmlEngl': bottomAreaHtmlEngl,
        'slug': slug
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#EditProjectActionUrl").val(),
        data: { projectSettings: settings, '__RequestVerificationToken': encodeURIComponent($("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val()) },
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            RefreshProjectsList();
            form.find("#divStatus-p").hide();
            form.closest('.modal-popup').dialog('close');
        }
    });
```

Frankly, I'm not too sure about how the anti-forgery token needs to get in there, but I think you get the idea. This way you're not fighting JavaScript and string concatenation.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I just use javascript object as a data parameter instead of encoding data into querystring form, the data isn't being concatinated and is normally delivered to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure bottomAreaHtml does not contain the '&' char.
If it does, and you don't escape it, it will "confuse" the model binder - since it is the separator for querystring values